# Add redux actions to login form?

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, jwt

I transitioned from a previous React app to a new template. Issue is i am quite confused about how redux is setup and how i can implement authentication.

LoginForm

```
// validation functions
const required = value => (value === null ? 'Required' : undefined);
const email = value =>
  value && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value) ? 'Invalid email' : undefined;

const LinkBtn = React.forwardRef(function LinkBtn(props, ref) {
  // eslint-disable-line
  return <NavLink to={props.to} {...props} innerRef={ref} />; // eslint-disable-line
});

// eslint-disable-next-line
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  // state = {
  //   showPassword: false,
  // };
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errors: {},
      showPassword: false,
    };
  }

  handleClickShowPassword = () => {
    const { showPassword } = this.state;
    this.setState({ showPassword: !showPassword });
  };

  handleMouseDownPassword = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    };

    loginUser(userData);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { classes, handleSubmit, pristine, submitting, deco } = this.props;
    const { showPassword } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Hidden mdUp>
          <NavLink to="/" className={classNames(classes.brand, classes.outer)}>
            <img src={logo} alt={brand.name} />
            {brand.name}
          </NavLink>
        </Hidden>
        <Paper className={classNames(classes.paperWrap, deco && classes.petal)}>
          <Hidden smDown>
            <div className={classes.topBar}>
              <NavLink to="/" className={classes.brand}>
                <img src={logo} alt={brand.name} />
                {brand.name}
              </NavLink>
              <Button
                size="small"
                className={classes.buttonLink}
                component={LinkBtn}
                to="/register"
              >
                <Icon className={classes.icon}>arrow_forward</Icon>
                Create new account
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Hidden>
          <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.title} gutterBottom>
            Sign In
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="caption" className={classes.subtitle} gutterBottom align="center">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          </Typography>
          <section className={classes.socmedLogin}>
            <div className={classes.btnArea}>
              <Button variant="outlined" size="small" className={classes.redBtn} type="button">
                <AllInclusive className={classNames(classes.leftIcon, classes.iconSmall)} />
                Socmed 1
              </Button>
              <Button variant="outlined" size="small" className={classes.blueBtn} type="button">
                <Brightness5 className={classNames(classes.leftIcon, classes.iconSmall)} />
                Socmed 2
              </Button>
              <Button variant="outlined" size="small" className={classes.cyanBtn} type="button">
                <People className={classNames(classes.leftIcon, classes.iconSmall)} />
                Socmed 3
              </Button>
            </div>
            <ContentDivider content="Or sign in with email" />
          </section>
          <section className={classes.formWrap}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div>
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                  <Field
                    name="email"
                    component={TextFieldRedux}
                    placeholder="Your Email"
                    label="Your Email"
                    required
                    validate={[required, email]}
                    className={classes.field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
              </div>
              <div>
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                  <Field
                    name="password"
                    component={TextFieldRedux}
                    type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                    label="Your Password"
                    InputProps={{
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                          <IconButton
                            aria-label="Toggle password visibility"
                            onClick={this.handleClickShowPassword}
                            onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDownPassword}
                          >
                            {showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                          </IconButton>
                        </InputAdornment>
                      ),
                    }}
                    required
                    validate={required}
                    className={classes.field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.optArea}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  className={classes.label}
                  control={<Field name="checkbox" component={CheckboxRedux} />}
                  label="Remember"
                />
                <Button
                  size="small"
                  component={LinkBtn}
                  to="/reset-password"
                  className={classes.buttonLink}
                >
                  Forgot Password
                </Button>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.btnArea}>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" type="submit">
                  Continue
                  <ArrowForward
                    className={classNames(classes.rightIcon, classes.iconSmall)}
                    disabled={submitting || pristine}
                  />
                </Button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </section>
        </Paper>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  init: bindActionCreators(loginUser, dispatch),
  loginUser:

});

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  pristine: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  deco: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const LoginFormReduxed = reduxForm({
  form: 'immutableExample',
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(LoginForm);

const reducerLogin = 'login';
const reducerUi = 'ui';
const FormInit = connect(
  state => ({
    force: state,
    initialValues: state.getIn([reducerLogin, 'usersLogin']),
    deco: state.getIn([reducerUi, 'decoration']),
  }),
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(LoginFormReduxed);

export default withStyles(styles)(FormInit);
```

login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import brand from 'dan-api/dummy/brand';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { LoginForm } from 'dan-components';
import styles from 'dan-components/Forms/user-jss';

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    valueForm: [],
  };

  submitForm(values) {
    const { valueForm } = this.state;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ valueForm: values });
      console.log(`You submitted:\n\n${valueForm}`);
      window.location.href = '/app';
    }, 500); // simulate server latency
  }

  render() {
    const title = brand.name + ' - Login';
    const description = brand.desc;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{title}</title>
          <meta name="description" content={description} />
          <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
          <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
          <meta property="twitter:title" content={title} />
          <meta property="twitter:description" content={description} />
        </Helmet>
        <div className={classes.container}>
          <div className={classes.userFormWrap}>
            <LoginForm onSubmit={values => this.submitForm(values)} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Login);
```

My authactions i am trying to add.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import setAuthToken from '../../utils/setAuthToken';

import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from '../constants/authConstants';

// Login - get user token
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post('/api/total/users/login', userData)
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage

      // Set token to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', JSON.stringify(token));
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data,
      }),
    );
};

// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded,
  };
};

// User loading
export const setUserLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOADING,
  };
};

// Log user out
export const logoutUser = history => dispatch => {
  // Remove token from local storage
  localStorage.removeItem('jwtTokenTeams');
  // Remove auth header for future requests
  setAuthToken(false);
  // Set current user to empty object {} which will set isAuthenticated to false
  dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));

  history.push('/dashboard');
};
```

and the authreducer

```
import { Map, fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { INIT } from '../constants/reduxFormConstants';
import { SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from '../constants/authConstants';

const isEmpty = require('is-empty');

const initialState = {
  usersLogin: Map({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {},
    loading: false,
    remember: false,
  }),
};
const initialImmutableState = fromJS(initialState);
export default function reducer(state = initialImmutableState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INIT:
      return state;
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
        user: action.payload,
      };
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I'm having a really hard time understaning how i can make this work together.

adding app.js

```
/**
 * app.js
 *
 * This is the entry file for the application, only setup and boilerplate
 * code.
 */

// Needed for redux-saga es6 generator support
import '@babel/polyfill';

// Import all the third party stuff
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';
import FontFaceObserver from 'fontfaceobserver';
import history from 'utils/history';
import 'sanitize.css/sanitize.css';

// Import root app
import App from 'containers/App';
import './styles/layout/base.scss';

// Import Language Provider
import LanguageProvider from 'containers/LanguageProvider';

// Load the favicon and the .htaccess file
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!../public/favicons/favicon.ico'; // eslint-disable-line
import 'file-loader?name=.htaccess!./.htaccess'; // eslint-disable-line

import configureStore from './redux/configureStore';

// Import i18n messages
import { translationMessages } from './i18n';

// Observe loading of Open Sans (to remove open sans, remove the <link> tag in
// the index.html file and this observer)
const openSansObserver = new FontFaceObserver('Open Sans', {});

// When Open Sans is loaded, add a font-family using Open Sans to the body
openSansObserver.load().then(() => {
  document.body.classList.add('fontLoaded');
});

// Create redux store with history
const initialState = {};
const store = configureStore(initialState, history);
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('app');

const render = messages => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </LanguageProvider>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE,
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  // Hot reloadable React components and translation json files
  // modules.hot.accept does not accept dynamic dependencies,
  // have to be constants at compile-time
  module.hot.accept(['./i18n', 'containers/App'], () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(MOUNT_NODE);
    render(translationMessages);
  });
}

// Chunked polyfill for browsers without Intl support
if (!window.Intl) {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(import('intl'));
  })
    .then(() =>
      Promise.all([import('intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js'), import('intl/locale-data/jsonp/de.js')]),
    ) // eslint-disable-line prettier/prettier
    .then(() => render(translationMessages))
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
} else {
  render(translationMessages);
}
// Install ServiceWorker and AppCache in the end since
// it's not most important operation and if main code fails,
// we do not want it installed
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('offline-plugin/runtime').install(); // eslint-disable-line global-require
}
```

the app component

```
import React from 'react';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotFound from 'containers/Pages/Standalone/NotFoundDedicated';
import store from '../../redux/configureStore';
import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from '../../redux/actions/authActions';
import setAuthToken from '../../utils/setAuthToken';
import Auth from './Auth';
import Application from './Application';
import ThemeWrapper, { AppContext } from './ThemeWrapper';
window.__MUI_USE_NEXT_TYPOGRAPHY_VARIANTS__ = true;



class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);

    return (
      <ThemeWrapper>
        <AppContext.Consumer>
          {changeMode => (
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Auth} />
              <Route
                path="/app"
                render={props => <Application {...props} changeMode={changeMode} />}
              />
              <Route component={Auth} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          )}
        </AppContext.Consumer>
      </ThemeWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

the auth component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Outer from '../Templates/Outer';
import {
  Login,
  LoginV2,
  LoginV3,
  Register,
  RegisterV2,
  RegisterV3,
  ResetPassword,
  LockScreen,
  ComingSoon,
  Maintenance,
  NotFound,
} from '../pageListAsync';

class Auth extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Outer>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          {/* <Route path="/login-v2" component={LoginV2} />
          <Route path="/login-v3" component={LoginV3} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/register-v2" component={RegisterV2} />
          <Route path="/register-v3" component={RegisterV3} /> */}
          <Route path="/reset-password" component={ResetPassword} />
          <Route path="/lock-screen" component={LockScreen} />
          {/* <Route path="/maintenance" component={Maintenance} />
          <Route path="/coming-soon" component={ComingSoon} /> */}
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Outer>
    );
  }
}

export default Auth;
```

Comment: Do you have a main App component? It is usually involved in checking local storage for a token on first page load, and blocks access to all routes except the login page if the user is not logged in. The tricky part is handling the loading state until you have verified if the user is logged in, if a request is necessary to do that (depends on your auth provider).

Comment: @timotgl Yes, i added the code for app.js, the app component and the auth component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain authentication using PLain redux is not quite possible because when ever you reload, the store get refreshed . However, redux has a functionality called **Persisted store**

**Persisted Store** store the data in memory and will not be refreshed with page reload or anything like that.

You can check this [Link](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

**Update with out persisted store:**

In that case, Get the IsLoggedin state from store.

**In App component**

```
const App = () => {
    const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken") !== null ? true: false

    return (
    <Router>
        
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} path="/dashboard">
                <Dashboard />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <Route path="/login">
                <Login authToken={authToken} />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);
```

**and then in private route component:**

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
    const { children, IsLoggedin, ...rest } = props;

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={({ location }) =>
                IsLoggedin ? (
                    children
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: '/login',
                            state: { from: location },
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: I had plain Redux authentication before. It checked the jwt token to keep user logged in or redirect to login if not.

Comment: In that case, check my updated answer please. Hope it will help you.

Comment: My issue and question has to do with the template i am using and which i posted in my question. The problem is that this method does not work considering the way redux and template routing is setup and i have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: This is not storing data "in memory", your snippet uses localStorage. And this method is not directly related to redux or even react. You can handle JWTs with lots of libraries. OP is already using localStorage in their example. "Persisted store" is not a redux concept. Do you mean preloaded state by any chance? Persisting the store to localStorage (or other) is done by several libraries in the redux ecosystem, but not by redux itself.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.   in my code snippet its using localstorage as I mentioned that it is an update without persisted store.